# Как объединить эти два цикла в один

Tags: php, mysql

Как объединить эти два цикла в один

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int, id_school  FROM datacenter WHERE surname = '$surname_parent' AND type = 'scholar' AND id_school IN                 ('$id_school', '$id_school1')");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<p>';
    echo $row[0].' '.$row[1];
    echo'</br>';
    echo $row[2]. '-' . $row[3];
    echo'</br>';
    echo'</p>';
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO helpschool (id_school, name) VALUES ('$id_school', '$name_parent')");
$da = mysql_query('SELECT `school` . `school`,  `street`, `city` FROM `helpschool`, `school` WHERE`helpschool` . `id_school` = `school` . `id_school` ');

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $da ))
{
    echo $row[2];
    echo '</br>';
    echo $row[1];
    echo '</br>';
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Я вижу ТРИ запроса.

Comment: @Zow сформируйте нормально вопрос...

Comment: ОМГ а зачем? выо о KISS слышали?( Keep It Simple Stupid ) ^.^

Реально не в ту сторону движитесь, вы лучше почитайте о нормальном структуированию, хотябы о отделении логики от представления ( для начала - хотя бы, в разные участки кода )

Comment: `</br>` - интересный тег

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам [сюда](http://govnokod.ru/) =) [[@Zow](/users/4425/zow)](/users/4425/zow), вам себя не жалко? SQL и HTML в одном файле это убийство)
 Ответ на Ваш вопрос (если я правильно понял, вы хотите объеденить результаты 2х этих селектов): никак. Но если вы совсем садомазо, то см. [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: а где держать SQL ?

Comment: В коде где же еще ^.^

Comment: @Zow, почитай всякие умные книжечки и статейки по проектированию. Для затравки на тебе линк http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller. MVC не панацея. есть своя туча недостатков, но для начала очень рекомендую ознакомиться просто ради того чтоб понять как отделить данные, логику и представления